# How to display _id of the item on the screen in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I've entered **_id** by myself, but how can I display them in console?
[image]

Here is the router:

```
router.get('/getCompetitions', (request, response) => {
    competitionTemplateCopy.find()
    .then(data => response.json(data))
    .catch(error => response.json(error))
});
```

Here is the function:

```
 const onClickThat = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/getCompetitions')
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  }
```

What I have:
[image]

I have only name but how can I display _id as well?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What does this have to do with either node or react? Also, what console do you want to display it in, and from what DB record? What is your existing code/environment?

Comment: I've made corrections in the question.

Comment: What is `competitionTemplateCopy`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are getting an array of objects.Store all the data in another vaiable then try this.

```
const [data,setData] =useState([])
     const onClickThat = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/getCompetitions')
        .then(response => setData(response)
      }

    data.map((e,i)=>{e._id})
```

I believe that this will work for you.

Comment: unfortunately not